# jQuery date picker apply date in 2 formats

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a date field that I need to show as "Dayname, dd/mm/yy" but I need to submit it as "mm-dd-yyyy"

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker and 2 input fields to try to achieve this. one to display the date, the other for submitting the date.

```
<h4>Event dates and times</h4>

        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="">Event (from) date<em>*</em></label>
            <input type="text" id="date1" value="" />
            <input type="text" id="en_event_date1" name="en_event_date_1" value="" required />
        </div><!-- /.form-field -->

        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="">Event end date (required for multi day events) <i>optional</i></label>
            <input type="text" id="date2" value="" />
            <input type="text" id="en_event_date2" name="en_event_date_2" value="" />
        </div><!-- /.form-field -->
```

.

```
$("#date1").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "DD, dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function() {
            var date = $('#date1').datepicker('getDate', "mm-dd-yy");
        }
    });
```

(not working)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`var date = $('#date1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();`

And submit this date variable.

Comment: No joy on that one unfortunatly, I just get the same format as the original